# NSString undeclared error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have been playing with the code from the create pdf tutorial on the iphonesdk site and I am stumped. I can create a pdf when I pass a float to NSString*text but when I try to take the value from a UITextField it comes up with an "input" undeclared. "input" is the name of the textfield which is properly declared and hooked up, it is working fine.
This is the code

```
enter code here     

UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);
CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext, 0, 20);
CGContextScaleCTM(pdfContext, 1.0, -1.0);
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", input.text];
[text drawInRect:CGRectMake(400, -410, 150, 300) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
UIGraphicsPopContext();
[text release];
```

Comment: Why are you using `+stringWithFormat:` at all instead of assigning directly to `text`? In other cases where you do actually need a separate instance you can always use `-copy`. Also *don't release `text`* - it is autoreleased.

Comment: Are you saying that the compiler gives you an error saying that the variable "input" has not been declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are have the following code at the top of your .h or .m file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

You can also put the code in your Prefix.pch file.

Also, make sure that you have @synthesize input; at the beginning of your @implementation and that you have not changed the name of "input" in the @synthesize statement. i.e. @synthesize input = input_;, if you have done that, you should put input_.text instead of input.text.

You can also use self.input.text.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, the NSLog displays the content I enter into the text field so its working ok, when assigning directly to text I still get the undeclared first use of function error. Yes the the compiler gives the error- "input" not declared.

Comment: Have imported UIkit, and everything is ok with @synthesize.

Comment: I think I know the problem, I am trying to pass input.text into a C Function and its a bit over my head

Comment: Instead of passing input.text into a cfunction, pass [input.text UTF8String]